# Dataframe assign blanket criteria if not matching

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe organized in the following manner for railcars.
I'd like to count by ['Railroad'], but only if it matches 'VER'. If not, I want 'Railroad' to reassign the value to 'NOT' and count by that.

Dataframe hierarchy:

```
df1 = df.reset_index().groupby(['Homebase','FINAL ETA','Code Description','L_E', 'Railroad'])['Code Description'].size()
```

Example output:

```
Homebase    FINAL ETA   Code Description        L_E  Railroad   
Rail2       2018-12-06  Arrival in yard         L    VER          1
            2019-01-04  Arrival in yard         L    VER         10
            2019-01-08  Arrival in yard         L    FIL         16
            2019-01-09  Arrival in yard         L    FIL          5
            2019-01-13  Arrival in yard         L    PAS          1
```

Desired output:

```
Homebase    FINAL ETA   Code Description        L_E  Railroad
Rail2       2018-12-06  Arrival in yard         L    VER          1
            2019-01-04  Arrival in yard         L    VER         10
            2019-01-08  Arrival in yard         L    NOT         16
            2019-01-09  Arrival in yard         L    NOT          5
            2019-01-13  Arrival in yard         L    NOT          1
```

Comment: What does the "following code" have to do with your question? Where is your actual data and [mcve]?

Comment: @coldspeed Sorry, I'm really struggling with how to ask questions well. I assumed that if I showed the dataframe formatting, it would help describe the end structure that I'm looking for. I'll paste some output.

Comment: @coldspeed I hope that's more clear with the output. The far right column is the number of railroad cars. I'd like to split those counts by whether or not it matches VERMONT.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see "VERMONT" anywhere.

Comment: @coldspeed I added the column in, it's "VER"

Comment: are you asking for a new column of 'NOT' but when Railroad = VER, have a count of VER? I think an expected output would help

Comment: @ksooklall Thanks for the suggestion, added desired output! does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like only the railroad column is changing, try this:

```
ver = (df1['Railroad'] == 'VER')
df1['Railroad'] = 'NOT'
df1.loc[ver, 'Railroad'] = 'VER'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Sorry if I'm confused - when I do that and print the output, it just outputs a single "VER"; no other columns or anything.

Comment: Is it because of `df` not `df1`

Comment: Yes, when I use df1 'Railroad' gives me a keyerror now

Comment: which `df` are you showing in the `Example Output:`, that `df` has the column and use my code above to give the `Desired Output:`

Comment: yessir, the df1 is what produces the current output in the Example Output

Comment: then the current code should get you the `Desired Output:`